# Calculate length lines within point buffer

Tags: line, buffer, intersection, summary

I have more than 184000 clients. I made a point buffer layer for all of them.
Also, I have a line layer of roads.
I want to calculate the length of lines (roads) within each buffer with a notebook and ArcPy code.
What is your suggestion code?
Do you think it will make much time? What is the substitution?

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import
env env.workspace = r"C:/Users/---/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/Notebook_clientRoadDensityBuffer/workspace"
clients_layer = "C:/Users/---/Road_Density/ArcGisLayer_shared_DelLaptop/Clients_3Filte.shp"
roads_layer = "C:/Users/---/Road_Density/ArcGisLayer_shared_DelLaptop/Road_Projected_selection10typeHighway.shp"
buffers_layer1 = "C:/Users/---/Documents/ArcGIS/Projects/Notebook_clientRoadDensityBuffer/Clients_buffer_1Mile1"
arcpy.analysis.Buffer(clients_layer,buffers_layer1, "1 Mile")
arcpy.AddField_management(buffers_layer1, "Road_Count", "LONG") 

fields=['Road_Count']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(buffers_layer1,fields ) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    buffer_geometry = row[0]
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(roads_layer, "INTERSECT", 
    buffer_geometry)
    count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(roads_layer).getOutput(0))
    row[0] = count
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

But an error appears:
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000732: Selecting Features: Dataset 0 does not exist or is not supported Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation)

Comment: What have you tried and where are you getting stuck? This is certainly possible with arcpy and notebooks, but it's hard to know where you need help without seeing your code attempt and where you're having trouble.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newcomer:-)
The code block is edited.

Comment: [Intersection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm), [Calculate](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) a line length field, [summarize](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm) road length per buffer id